# How to override product listing page with custom queries

Tags: module, prestashop

I create module that display filters in left column. I want to run this module on categories page. I want custom queries to get products data and create pagination for this data. But I don't know how to override these functionalists in my custom module.

Any functions or hooks that I use when queering products.

Category page may be like this

```
http://localhost/prestashop/2-men
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the hook "actionProductListOverride".

This hook will give you an array in parameters containing 3 references:
- nbProducts
- catProducts
- hookExecuted

You need to set the number of products returned by your filter in nbProducts, the list of products in catProducts, and true in hookExecuted (if you keep hookExecuted set to false, PrestaShop will consider that you finally did not override the list).

You can find an example in the free native blocklayered module, look at the hookProductListAssign($params) function.

This hook is called in /controllers/front/CategoryController.php, in assignProductList().